# How to remove a piece of text from string in apex

Tags: apex

I have a string body that is

> "
>
> Product is processed
>
> Hide quoted text
>
> On Wed, Apr 6, 2022 at 5:52 PM Maura restworking@gmail.com wrote:
> New product  Has been dispatched  : product info

From the above string
I don't need the text from hide quoted text to till end "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split as an option.

```
String newMessage = incomingMessage.split('Hide quoted text',2)[0];
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell what's the second parameter '2 for and [0] for?

Comment: @Astriopa 2 limits the split to two parts, since we don't care about anything after that point. `[0]` is accessing the zeroth index of the `List<String>` that split returns.

Comment: Thank you Sfdcfox